# Magento 2 - Rewrite url from custom module

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

In magento 1 I can rewrite url in my custom module `etc/config.xml` like this:

```
<global>
        <rewrite>
            <digi_url>
                <from><![CDATA[/digisearcher\/feed.xml/]]></from>
                <to><![CDATA[digi/index/index/]]></to>
                <complete>1</complete>
            </digi_url> 
        </rewrite>
</global>
```

how can I achieve this in my Magento2 custom module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a custom `Router` class to match your criteria and then redirect to your desired path

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_routest" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Router\CustomRouter</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="cacheable" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Controller/Router/CustomRouter

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Router;

use Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;

class CustomRouter implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface
{   

    private $actionFactory;
    private $response;

    public function __construct(
        ActionFactory $actionFactory,
        ResponseInterface $response

    ) {
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
        $this->response = $response;
    }

    public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $identifier = $request->getOriginalPathInfo(); //to read the route
        /** Apply Url logic here */
        return $this->_response->setRedirect('route/controller/action'); //redirect 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, we don't have that option in magento 2. Did you try the standard url rewrite option in admin panel?

You can do it in controller level by extending the controller OR can do it in .htaccess file level Or via routes.yaml in case if you are using magento cloud.

Answer (score 0):

For the custom URL rewrite magento 2 allowed us the concept of the custom router, you need to implement that things into your custom extension like the Magento CMS module do.

> 1. app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\frontend\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="customsearch" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Extension\Controller\Router</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">50</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> 2. app\code\Vendor\Extension\Controller\Router.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Controller;

class Router implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory
     */
    protected $actionFactory;

    public function __construct(.....
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory,
        .....) {
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
    }


    public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');

       //PUT YOUR CUSTOM LOGIC HERE FOR THE URL


        $request->setModuleName('digi')->setControllerName('index')->setActionName('index');
        // if you want to pass any parameter ->setParam('variable', $value);

        return $this->actionFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward,['request' => $request]);
    }
}
```